# April 2016 CU KB 2920721 does not increment Build Version

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I just applied the April 2016 CU [KB 2920721](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/KB/2920721) to my SharePoint 2016 farm and noticed the build number did not increment to 16.0.4366.100 as expected.

I tried to reinstall but I was told by the dialog that it is already applied.

Looking at the Servers in Farm page the status says "No Action Required"

Has anyone noticed this?  Any ideas why this is occurring or how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, this is by design and now onwards it is normal.

Not every CU increment the build number, only if CU touch the configuration schema n update it.

Now, you can go Central Admin > upgrade and migration and check the patch status.

On this page you will see that ur CU applied and version number 4366.

Check the link below http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34002.sharepoint-2016-build-numbers.aspx